# What degree do you need to become a game designer,programmer,developer.etc

Tags: education

I was wintering what degree do you need in order to become a game designer,programmer or developer. 
P.S i mean people who work for companies such as riot or ubisoft,etc

Comment: First thing you need is the ability to read help pages to see how assets (like this website) are supposed to be used.

Comment: You don't, you need aptitude.

Comment: Au contraire mes frères, you need pizzazz.

Answer (score 3):

Well I mean, I believe something like computer science would help. But I think publishers and development studios mainly look for good experience. I'm completely new to game development and I don't have the money to be a full time student. But I'm developing a few very small, but professionally made and presentable games in my spare time to create a portfolio. That should be a good start to getting hired somewhere

You also may want to consider revising your question to be a bit more specific. Do you know what kind of work you want to do? Coding? Animation? Design? There's a LOT that goes into game development. I would recommend researching different career paths in the game industry first.

Comment: This is a very good answer to a question that is way off-topic for this site. :)